# ASP.NET HTTPHandler not throwing exception when one is expected

Tags: asp.net, http, httphandler

I have an HttpHandler class (implements IHttphandler) where the path defined for the handler in web.config is *.jpg. I am requesting a Jpg image in my page. Within the HTTP Handler I am writing to a file in the filesystem. By mistake I was trying to write to a non existant directory. This should have thrown an exception but the execution simply proceeds.Ofcourse no file is written. But if I give a proper directory the file is written correctly.Is there anything special about HttpHandler Exceptions.
See part of the code

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context){

        File.WriteAllLines(context.Request.ApplicationPath+@"\"+"resul.log",new string[]{"Entered JPG Handler"});
```

If I  put a breakpoint on the File.WriteAllLines statement and then step over it I can see an  exception occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Request.Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.applicationpath.aspx) returns the application's virtual application root path on the server. For example: "/YourApp", as opposed to "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\YourApp."

What's likely happening is **File.WriteLine(...)** *is* actually writing the file somewhere, probably in the same folder as your web server process.

**EDIT:** Here's some of the *likely* places to check:

- *if using built-in VS2008 web server*

  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
     Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\9.0`
- *if using built-in VS2010 web server*

  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
     Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\10.0`
- *if using IIS*

  `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv` or `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv`

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET might only be intercepting ASP.NET file extensions like .aspx and not processing other types of content (i.e. maybe your jpegs are being skipped altogether).

[These are the regular file extensions mapped to ASP.NET for processing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wawkw1c.aspx).

You might have to map other file extensions (like .jpeg, .jpg, etc) in IIS to the ASP.NET processor - [**This Microsoft article tells how**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515343.aspx).